# How do I build Polymer Element?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, polymer, web-component

There is currently an open bug on running `polymer build` on elements: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/338

Does anyone have some Grunt scripts (or description of what exactly it does) for accomplishing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the Yeoman generator from: https://github.com/seaneking/generator-polymer-element

It has a very nice list of features set up in the Gulp build system. The build system includes Babel ES6 transpiling, Rollup, PostCSS, inline asset processing, and BrowserSync.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on the element default imports.
The tree of the directorie should be:

```
element/
  bower_components/
  build/
  demo/
  teste/
  bower.json
  element-test.html
  index.html
  READEME.md
```

The imports on index.html and elemt-test.html are calling for "../dependency", but the correct is to call "bower_components/dependency", it will work if you just fix the paths.

Comment: I'm sure that they'll fix this path issue on some of the next releases

Answer (score 1):

When i use the [Polyer Cli](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli) to do `polymer init` and choose `element` it cannot natively build because of relative pathing.

To solve this I bower install my element into another project and navigate to my element inside of `bower_components`. In this space all the relative paths are correct and you can run `vulcanize` commands there with [vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize).

I hope that helps people who struggled like I did.